# Refresh table only when modal closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a script that reloads the entire page when modal is closed, I want it to reload just the div that contains the table instead of the entire page.

the div is:

```
<div class="result_data" id="result_data"> Table here </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // use ajax, call the PHP
    $.ajax({
        url: 'pages/t-log.php', // path of lelong
        success: function(response){
            $('#result_data').html(response);
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

My code is:

```
    <script>
$('#modal-buy, #modal-sell').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { 
    location.reload();
});
    </script>
```

I was able to do it using:

```
$('#modal-buy, #modal-sell').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { 
    $('#result_data').load(document.URL +  ' #result_data');
    //location.reload();
});
```

but the new challenge is that the ID is already being used to populate the table, so it reloads but doesn't populate the table.

Comment: whare is the div that you want to reload? how data is assigned in it?

Comment: <div class="result_data" id="result_data"> reload this </div>

Comment: You should read up on something called AJAX. Especially jQuery AJAX is very nicely simplified to make it easy to understand.

Comment: Fetch an entire page, just to than focus and copy a small portion of HTML by ID is nonsense. Back in the days might have been *"look ma I did thiz"*. Today I might ask, why? Also, by doing it the way you do it currently, loading #XY into #XY might only get you into the trouble of having duplicate ID elements one inside the other (unless you use *replace*).

Comment: @Martin FYI jQuery's `.load()` method *is* AJAX.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, but if the data isn't loaded, it means the approach is wrong. If the AJAX logic is fetching the data appropriately, it'd work. Another case is that he dynamically attempts to populate the table outside of the AJAX call, so the table is reloaded, but never populated, or the table is trying to populate before the reload.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan what solution do you propose?